# c# implement interface method with parameter of subclass type

Tags: c#, class-hierarchy

I have this desired class hierarchy:

```
interface IClass
{
    string print(IClass item);
}

class MyClass : IClass
{
    // invalid interface implementation
    // parameter type should be IClass not MyClass
    string print(MyClass item)
    { return item.ToString(); }
}
```

I tried to solve interface implementation problem by using generic types as next with no success:

```
interface IClass
{
    string print<T>(T item) where T : IClass;
}

class MyClass : IClass
{
    string print<T>(T item) where T : MyClass
    { return item.ToString(); }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should make the interface itself generic and give the implementing class the desired type.

Comment: How about not having the parameter in the print method and make each subclass inject the IClass implementation into the contructor or a sertter.

Comment: The toString Method is inherited from Object, so why do you really need to have `print(MyClass item)` and not just `print(Object item)`?
Do you hide this method?

Comment: It's just a simplified example of my real class hierarchy.

Answer (score 14):

Make your interface generic

```
interface IClass<T>  where T : IClass<T>
{
     string print(T item);
}

class MyClass : IClass<MyClass>
{
    public string print(MyClass item)
    { 
       return item.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that though this does work, (1) it is confusing, and (2) it does not necessarily enforce the restriction you wish to enforce. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx for some thoughts on this pattern.

Comment: @Eric, What do you suggest to solve the problem in a more clear manner?

Comment: can we use polymorphism with this solution?

Answer (score 11):

It's helpful to understand why this is illegal. The feature you want is *formal parameter type covariance*, and very few languages offer it. (Eiffel, I think has this as a feature.) It is not often found in languages because it is not safe!  Let me illustrate with an example:

```
class Animal {}
class Lion : Animal { public void Roar() { } }
class Giraffe : Animal { }
interface IFoo { void M(Animal a); }
class C : IFoo
{
    public void M(Lion lion) { lion.Roar(); }
}
class P
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IFoo foo = new C();
        foo.M(new Giraffe()); 
    }
}
```

And we just made a giraffe roar.

If you look at all those type conversions, the only one that can sensibly be made illegal is matching `C.M(Giraffe)` to `IFoo.M(Animal)`.

Now, formal parameter type *contravariance* is *typesafe* but it is not legal in C# except in some very limited circumstances.  If C# supported it, which it does not, then you could safely do something like this:

```
interface IBar { void M(Giraffe g); }
class D : IBar
{
    public void M(Animal animal) { ... }
}
class P
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IBar bar = new D();
        bar.M(new Giraffe()); 
    }
}
```

See what happened there? IFoo.M says "I can take a giraffe", and C.M says "I can accept any giraffe because in fact I can accept any animal".  That would be typesafe if C# supported it, but it only supports it in two ways:

- Contravariant generic delegate and interface conversions.
- Contravariant method group conversions to delegate types.

An example of the first is that an expression of type `IComparable<Animal>` may be assigned to a variable of type `IComparable<Giraffe>` by the same logic: a method that compares two animals can be used where a method that compares two giraffes is needed.  This was added in C# 4.

An example of the second is:

```
delegate void MyFunction(Giraffe g);
...
D d = new D();
MyFunction myfunc = d.M;
```

Again, we need a function that takes a Giraffe, and we supply one that takes any Animal. This feature was added in C# 2.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass **IClass** as parameter to your method.

```
interface IClass
{
  string print(IClass item);
}

class MyClass : IClass
{
  public string print(IClass item)
  { return item.ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: My requirement is that the print method of MyClass should receive parameter of exactly MyClass and not of another IClass subclasses.

Comment: For now if we just ignore that one should program to interfaces - not implementation. whats wrong with the following interface?

interface IClass { string print(MyClass item); }

Comment: Nothing. That's fine. But like said below @Eric Lippert it's confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here's A solution that will get you compiling at least:

```
interface IClass
{
    string print<T>(T item) where T : IClass;
}

class MyClass : IClass
{   
    string print(IClass item) => item is MyClass i ? i.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```